# date from a String To Date() Conversion (Date is not correct after conversion) swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am using following code to convert string to Date

```
    let strTime = "2015-07-27 19:29"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    var date = formatter.date(from: strTime)
```

but its output as follows

[image]

we can see time in the Date is not correct (13:59)as we given on string (19:29)

Comment: Where you you live? In which Timezone? For instance, in France with your current code, I get "2015-07-27 17:29:00 +0000". But that's because we are in summer and there is 2 hours difference with UTC.

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to the time zone...

Answer (score 0):

Add TimeZone to your formatter :

```
let strTime          = "2015-07-27 19:29"
let formatter        = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
formatter.timeZone   = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") // Whatever your timeZone is
var date             = formatter.date(from: strTime)
print(date)
```

Comment: Only do this if you want to treat `strTime` as being in the UTC timezone. That may or may not be appropriate.